# How do I query for the latest Beanstalk ami of a specific platform to use in packer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami, packer

I'm not creating a "custom platform" for Beanstalk, I just want to build a custom ami from the latest Beanstalk ami for my platform. This has been really frustrating because I can't find good documentation for this.

I can get the latest ami arn like this:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-platform-version \
    --platform-arn "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2::platform/IIS 10.0 running on 64bit Windows Server 2019/2.5.0" \
    --query 'PlatformDescription.CustomAmiList[?VirtualizationType==`hvm`].ImageId'
```

But I want to do this in packer like this:

```
"source_ami_filter": {
  "filters": {
    "virtualization-type": "hvm",
    "name": "*Windows_Server-2012-R2*English-64Bit-Base*",
    "root-device-type": "ebs"
  },
  "most_recent": true,
  "owners": "amazon"
},
```

What is the correct source_ami_filter for getting latest version of IIS 10.0 running on 64bit Windows Server 2019? It seems like it calls the describe-images method but I can't figure out how to get Beanstalk ami with that.

This returns nothing for example:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters Name=name,Values='IIS 10.0 running on 64bit Windows Server 2019*'
```

### Edit

Using aws elasticbeanstalk describe-platform-version I get this

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-platform-version --region us-east-1 --platform-arn "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/IIS 10.0 running on 64bit Windows Server 2019/2.5.0" --query 'PlatformDescription.CustomAmiList[?VirtualizationType==`hvm`].ImageId'
```

Returns: ami-0fd1bbf3adf035706

but describe images shows the latest image is something different. I want to target a specific platform and version ("arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2::platform/IIS 10.0 running on 64bit Windows Server 2019/2.5.0")

Using describe-images on the name string shows something different:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --filters 'Name=name,Values=aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-??????????.x86_64-WindowsServer2019-V2-hvm-*' --region us-east-1 --query 'reverse(sort_by(Images, &CreationDate))[].[CreationDate, Name, ImageId]' --output text

2020-02-21T23:32:24.000Z    aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2020.02.12.x86_64-WindowsServer2019-V2-hvm-202002212241   ami-044ff22e194ea0ba3
2020-02-21T19:07:22.000Z    aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2020.02.12.x86_64-WindowsServer2019-V2-hvm-202002211814   ami-0fe9d8b6587daca04
2020-01-19T23:02:54.000Z    aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2020.01.15.x86_64-WindowsServer2019-V2-hvm-202001192219   ami-0fd1bbf3adf035706
2020-01-19T03:46:03.000Z    aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2020.01.15.x86_64-WindowsServer2019-V2-hvm-202001190252   ami-0e70abb9312eb34e5
2020-01-11T01:12:23.000Z    aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2019.12.16.x86_64-WindowsServer2019-V2-hvm-202001110020   ami-08df7b236ed19e461
2020-01-10T00:02:51.000Z    aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2019.12.16.x86_64-WindowsServer2019-V2-hvm-202001092311   ami-0664773b5a898cc82
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-??????????.x86_64-WindowsServer2019-V2-hvm-*`.

As an exemple, the following cli command will get all the current available images for IIS 10.0 running on 64bit Windows Server 2019, sort by reverse creation date and take the first AMI ID from the list, which is the one that you target.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --filters 'Name=name,Values=aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-??????????.x86_64-WindowsServer2019-V2-hvm-*' 'Name=state,Values=available' --query 'reverse(sort_by(Images, &CreationDate))[:1].ImageId' --output text --region=us-east-2
```

Output:

> ami-0e76ecdeebe63dc5c

Comment: see my comments this does not seem to work. the problem is the "Name" doesnt seem to include the specific eb platform and version